# First django project,showing error no module named 'polls'

Tags: python, django

I followed the Django official document,and I am writing the poll app.

And  in the mysite package, it says   No module named 'polls' when I run it,how can I solve it?

my python is 3.6,my Django is 1.10.2,

this is my directory

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── polls
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── admin.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    └── apps.py
```

mysite\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import polls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   ]
```

INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'polls',

 ]
```

And there is another problem in the document,the document types:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
   ]
```

When i run it,it says cannot import name 'views',i delete the from .,then it works.But the problem above still don't solve,can anyone tell me why??

Comment: Don't link images. Either include them, or better yet, copy-paste the code as text and use a code block to format the code. Don't make us follow links to off-site resources please.

Comment: Please put the code of your project  .py files.

Answer (score 6):

I met this issue, it cost me two days, the root cause is filename of urls.py is wrong like ' urls.py'.
There is a blank before urls.py in ' urls.py'.
It worked when I fixed the polls/' urls.py' to polls/urls.py.

Comment: If you check the post, there is no such a space before `urls.py`... so?

Answer (score 6):

Please check **polls/urls.py**: it should be like this:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Also check **mysite/urls.py**: it should be like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And finally check **polls/views.py**: it should be like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

And I think it's not a good idea to add anything manually to the INSTALLED_APPS = [ ] section. At least for this tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Despite attached folder schema, I have a suspicion, that an application `polls` was started one folder too high. Means, in folder "`You_want_to_keep_Your_project`" You have: `mysite>mysite`. And You should start application from inside first `mysite`, but You started it just in folder "`You_want_to_keep_Your_project`".
I did so in this tutorial, and had the same problem.

PS. You don't need to declare `polls` in settings at this moment (though it's not the problem if You did, of course)

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, I thought I had to create the file `urls.py` on the parent `mysite` folder (the project folder), but it is actually inside the folder `mysite` that sits inside the project folder with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have the `polls` app installed.

Go to `settings.py`, inside it find `INSTALLED_APPS = [...]` and add `'polls',` to that list.

Comment: but l have added "polls" to INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Well Django isn't seeing it, so something's not right. Run these three lines from your project dir: `python manage.py shell` `from django.conf import settings` `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` and paste the result here. Also you can delete the line `import polls` in `urls.py`, Django will handle that automatically with the string.

Comment: @Mr.tang Show your INSTALLED_APPS section of your settings.py.

Comment: @almost a beginner Okay,l have posted it

Comment: @Mr.tang I don't th

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this situation. But when I copy the code from documentation to file, the problem has solved. I thought the version of django you used may not be correct. Reference here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/install/

Answer (score 1):

In the pre-entered entry of the file, it says:

```
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
```

So, try entering:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from polls import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

but afterwards you need to import a few things to the polls\urls.py file because if you don't it will give an Error saying that the file is empty.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns =[

]
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue too, but in my case it was because I had inadvertently added the changes intended in the tutorial for `mysite/urls.py` into `mysite/urls.conf`.

Creating `mysite/urls.py` and populating as per the tutorial solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this problem is related to the setup environment.

For your first problem, try `url(r'^polls/', include('mysite.polls.urls')),`

For your second problem try `from polls import views`, or just stick with `import views`.

If this doesn't work, I suggest restarting the tutorial, because clearly the environment has not been setup accordingly. The code is perfectly fine in the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

Is the TCP port that you are using, available? The example tells to try out  `http://localhost:8000/polls/` but it can so happen that port 8000 is already being used.
Use the command (in Windows)

```
netstat -an|findstr 8080
```

in Linux, the command should be

```
netstat -an|grep 8080
```

to check the availability of the port 8080 (I picked up the port number randomly).

If the target port is available (for the sake of argument, let's say), type the following command in the command prompt to start the Django's built-in lightweight web server:

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

I am assuming the above is run at the location where manage.py is located. 
If everything is fine so far, the lightweight webserver will kick in.

Then, in your browser, you should try http://localhost:8080/polls/ which should show `Hello, world. You're at the polls index.`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `'mysite',` before `'polls',` in the `INSTALLED_APPS = []` section. In addition every app name should be written as `'xyz',` here usually miss on syntax please check that. Once you confirm & check this please run `python manage.py migrate polls`.

Make sure you are running this in (VENV) and not in (BASE). After this `python manage.py runserver` command will start the server specifying the IP.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt you are passed this issue now but I had the same problem, and for me this was the root cause. I have no idea why but in my settings.py I ended up with the line;

```
from mysite.polls.apps import PollsConfig
```

in my settings.py, not sure where it come from as I searched the tutorial and it doesn't say to add it. I found it by searching through my entire directory for;

> mysite.polls

Answer (score 0):

my case is that I created the filename 'ulrs.py' instead of 'urls.py'.